# Different results when using the LayoutInflator's inflate methods

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I want to know how the `LayoutParams` will work on `LayoutInflator`. And what is difference between:

```
LinearLayout childLayout=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.childitemlayout, null); //FIRST WAY
LinearLayout childLayout=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.childitemlayout, container,false); //SECOND WAY
```

Because, both methods gives me different result.
Actually second inflate method are gives me correct result for both child layout change, but First method will gives me different result.

Here is my code:

```
MainActivity.Java

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout mainLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            LinearLayout childLayout=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.childitemlayout, null); //First WAY
//          LinearLayout childLayout=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.childitemlayout, mainLayout,false);  //SECOND WAY
            mainLayout.addView(childLayout);
        }
    }


main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>


childitemlayout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#525f67">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button"
            android:gravity="center"
            />


</LinearLayout>  <!-- Both ways gives different result  --> 


<!-- 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#525f67">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Button"
            android:gravity="center"
            />


</LinearLayout> Both method gives SAME result   -->
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main difference between the two `inflate()` methods is the second parameter(the `ViewGroup` parameter) and its use in setting the proper `LayoutParams` for the root view of the inflated layout file. This is important because the `LayoutParams` keep various layout attributes of the view(like width, height, positioning rules etc) and are required so the parent of that view can properly show the view.

The first method basically says: *build the hierarchy view from this layout file but don't assign `LayoutParams` to the root of the inflated hierarchy(maybe because the parent isn't know yet), also don't attach the inflated view to a parent*.

The second inflate method says: *build the hierarchy view from this layout file and **also assign the proper `LayoutParams`(based on the second parameter given to the inflate method) to the root of the inflated hierarchy**, also don't attach the inflated view to a parent*.

In the first case, the root of the inflated layout file(`R.layout.childitemlayout`) will not have any `LayoutParams` set on it(the `inflate` method didn't assign any because the second parameter is `null` and it doesn't know which type of `LayoutParams` to generate), so your fixed width/height values are lost. Later when you'll do `mainLayout.addView(childLayout);` the `mainLayout` will check the `LayoutParams` of the `childLayout`, see that those are `null` and will automatically set an instance of the `LayoutParams`(using its `generateDefaultLayoutParams()` method). This method, in the particular case of a horizontal `LinearLayout`, will return an instance of `LayoutParams` where the width/height will be set to `WRAP_CONTENT`. So your `childLayout` will end up with `WRAP_CONTENT` as its size instead of the fixed values you set on them.

In the second case, the `inflate` method sees that you suggested the `LinearLayout` `mainLayout` as the `ViewGroup` used for generating the `LayoutParams`. This means that the fixed values(that you used for the width/height) retrieved from the layout file  can be stored in a proper instance of the `LayoutParams`. When you'll do `mainLayout.addView(childLayout);`, `mainLayout` will see that `childLayout`  has the proper `LayoutParams` instance(which has the values used in the layout file) and doesn't call its `generateDefaultLayoutParams()`.

Comment: Thank you very much Luksprog for your help. I accept your answer. Thanks ones again for this knowledgeable information.

Comment: this answer is surely of great quality and helped me understand. thank you very much. cannot upvote this enough